# Changing arrays to direct links with VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Can anyone help me with a peice of VBA code that I can run that will change an array block into direct links to cells.

Basically the problem is that I have spreadsheets that other people have constructed and they are full of arrays linking to other sheets. I have to format them and add extra rows etc and arrays are not very flexible in this respect and I don't want to waste 3 or 4 days relinking everything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are array formulas in your worksheet they cannot be converted to direct links.

Cells in an array formula must always be adjacent - you can't have intervening cells that are not part of the array. That's just the way array formulas in Excel work.

You can try to convert to values, make your changes & then reenter the array formulas.